# rails_admin: browsing collections of unknown structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, rails-admin

I am trying to use rails_admin w/mongoid to show a tabular view of a mongo collection. The problem is that I do not know the structure of the objects in the collection beforehand. rails_admin, AFAIK, is based on the model definition.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Rails_admin depends on config/initializers/rails_admin.rb running at startup.  The file is probably generated from your schema so it wouldn't dynamically update if you change your object structure after startup.  You might be able to extend the rails_admin code to dynamically change the config.